# What is the iOS developer payment schedule?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I'm planning to release an iPhone app next week. I have read that Apple pays out 45 days after the end of month (if threshold is reached). My developer account is linked to an address in India if that makes any difference.

So, if I reach the threshold in May, is it safe to assume I will get paid in the beginning of July?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from https://discussions.apple.com/message/23256906#23256906 you don't get paid for a month after you hit the threshold for payment of $150. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Developers get paid within 45 days of the last day of the month. For example, the amount you earned in March should be paid to you before mid-May. For my case in March, 2015, I got paid on April 30.

Also note that the minimum threshold depends on the currency and country pair Apple set. If you decide to get paid in the pair Apple set (e.g. HKD in Hong Kong or JPY in Japan), it's $10 USD or equivalent. If not, it's $150 USD.

This information is from [Apple's documentation in iTunes Connect](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/books/faq/Payments%20and%20Financial%20Reports_Getting%20Paid#).

> When will I be paid?
>
> Payments are made within 45 days of the last day of the month in which
>   book purchases were made. To receive payment, you must have provided
>   all required banking and tax information and documentation, as well as
>   meeting the minimum payment threshold.
>
> If your bank and bank account currency is listed in this table, you
>   must exceed a minimum payment threshold of $10 USD. All other bank
>   countries and bank account currencies must exceed a minimum payment
>   threshold of $150 USD.

Answer (score 1):

So the reality is that Apple, unlike other app stores, uses a special fiscal payment calendar where months don't start on the 1st and don't end 30/31 days later.

Instead of using standard calendar months, Apple sets up its own fiscal calendar and uses it to pay developers. Apple’s fiscal calendar is divided into quarters, each with one 35-day fiscal month and two 28-day fiscal months. Furthermore the fiscal calendar is only 364 days, so every 5 years or so Apple has to add an extra week to the December fiscal month to account for leap days and the 365th day of each year.

Hence, based on our expertise with Apple Payments, we at Braavo Capital have created a [Apple Payments Calendar](https://www.getbraavo.com/apple-payments-calendar) tool that tells you exactly when to expect your Apple payments.